# How to show more than one dimension attribute side by side as columns?

Tags: ssas

So, if I have a dimension 'User' with attributes 'First Name' and 'Last Name', how would I get them to show side by side?

What I get now when I add attributes is this:
Last Name 1
  First Name 1
Last Name 2
  First Name 2
...

And I want to have this:

Last Name 1  First Name 1
Last Name 2  First Name 2
...

I know I can make a named calculation, but this is over-simplified example for what really need.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think your formatting has gone wrong somehow - is what you want one row per User, with columns Last Name and First Name?

You can do this with calculated members looking at the .Properties("attribute name") of the .CurrentMember of your User dimension.

Using the Adventure Works sample (2014), I'm using Customers as an example.  They don't have Last Name and First Name attributes, so I'm using their Education and Marital Status attributes instead - I hope you get the idea:

```
WITH MEMBER Measures.CustomerEducation AS [Customer].
[Customer].CurrentMember.Properties("Education")
MEMBER Measures.CustomerMaritalStatus AS [Customer].
[Customer].CurrentMember.Properties("Marital Status")
SELECT
{Measures.CustomerEducation,Measures.CustomerMaritalStatus} ON 0,
[Customer].[Customer].Customer ON 1
FROM [Adventure Works]
```